# A homeomorphism between $[0,1]$ and $[0,1]^n$?

Tags: general-topology, analysis, algebraic-topology

I do know that there are no homeomorphisms between open set of different $\mathbb R^n$, but how about between compact sets, e.g., $[0,1]$ and $[0,1]^n$ ?

Comment: Are you aware of the concept of a cut-point?

Comment: If you remove a single point from $(0, 1)$, then $[0, 1]$ is no longer connected. By contrast, removing any single point from $[0, 1]^n$ leaves a set which is still connected for all $n > 1$.

Comment: @DanRust and Mark Saving,  Thanks for the clarification.

Comment: A more interesting question would be, hence, why there are no homeomorphisms between $[0,1]^n$ and $[0,1]^m$.

Comment: @principal-ideal-domain You can solve that question with homology groups. To show there's no homeomorphism between $[0, 1]^{n +1}$ and $[0, 1]^m$, $m > n + 1$, note that you can remove a single point from $[0, 1]^{n + 1}$ and that the resulting space has a nontrivial $n$th homology group. But this is not true for $[0, 1]^m$.

Comment: Another method: the notion of topological dimension: see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lebesgue_covering_dimension